# Who did develop the transfer function formalism?

Tags: math-history, greens-function

[Transfer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function) is something every engineer studies during his early career. I thought people like Fourier and Green had developed it, but apparently it stems from Kubo's [linear response formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_response_function). Is it true?

This formalism also arises in the [LTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time-invariant_theory) (linear time invariant) theory.

For example from the wiki [linear response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_response_function) page:

> Consider a damped harmonic oscillator with input given by an external
>   driving force $h(t)$,
>
> $$\ddot{x}(t)+\gamma \dot{x}(t)+\omega_0^2 x(t)=h(t). $$
>
> The complex-valued Fourier transform of the linear response function
>   is given by:
>
> $$\tilde{\chi}(\omega) = \frac{\tilde{x}(\omega)}{\tilde{h}(\omega)} =
> \frac{1}{\omega_0^2-\omega^2+i\gamma\omega}$$

Comment: You may want to disambiguate that this is not about the transfer from group theory or topology.